# Выборка из представлений по количеству отправителей

Tags: sql, oracle

В базе данных Oracle создано представление view_transactions  для проверки денежных транзакций (с такими столбцами, как id, receiver, sender, data, amount, country и т. д.), которое содержит 10 таблиц, связанных друг с другом. Итак, у нас есть запрос с отбором по количеству транзакций на заданный период времени:

```
SELECT *
FROM view_transactions
WHERE TRUNC (datedoc) >= DATE ('01/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  AND TRUNC (datedoc) <= DATE ('29/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  AND receiver IN (
    SELECT receiver
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT (receiver) counter, receiver
      FROM view_transactions
      WHERE TRUNC (datedoc) >= DATE ('01/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        AND TRUNC (datedoc) <= DATE ('29/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
      GROUP BY receiver
    )
    WHERE counter >= 13
  )
ORDER BY id
```

Здесь цифра 13, сказано отображать получателей, получивших деньги более 13 раз в течение месяца.

И теперь мне нужно усложнить этот запрос. Также необходимо искать , количество отправляющих 3 и более раз, и получателей, получивших деньги 13 раз. Если отправители встречаются 3 и более раз, значит, необходимо сгруппировать получателя и суммировать сумму.

Например, в этом месяце Билл 13 раз получал денежные переводы от разных отправителей, а от Dell он получал 5 раз на суммы 120$, 250$, 312$, 500$ и 50$. Джон и Майкл отправили Биллу по 4 раза каждый.
Итак, необходимо отобразить:

| id | receiver | sender | sum | date | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill | Dell | 1232 | 02.01.2023 | .... |
| 2 | Bill | John | some summa | 20.01.2023 | .... |
| 3 | Bill | Michael | some summa | 21.01.2023 | .... |

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь это сделать?

Comment: Предоставьте(желательно в качесте sql-insert) исходные данные и как должны выглядеть сгруппированные данные

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: @SwaD смотрите, результат запроса должны показать в Excel. А по поводу сгруппировка других колонок например Dell отправил 2 раза в долларах и 3 раза в евро, и соответственно две разные информации, и вот эти двух разных валют надо показать в одну строку разделяя запятой или точка запятой чтобы результат был в примеру: ```Bill     Dell      1232      USD;EURO     data etc...```, и других остальных колонок точно так, исключая data, receiver, sender и amount. Надеюсь ясно доложил?)

Comment: Если вы сами составили показанный запрос, то и с изменением должны справится. Подсказака для одного из возможных вариантов: сгруппируйте транзакции, которые подходят под условие, и которые не подходят, а потом объедините результаты с помощью UNION.

Comment: Описание несколько запутанное. Сначала вроде получается, что нужно объединять только транзакции отправителей, отправивших получателям 13 и более переводов деньги три и более раз. Но потом вы суммируете по две транзакции от Джона и Майкла. В последнем случае можно обойтись и без UNION, просто просуммировав все транзакции пар получатель-отправитель и отобрав получателей 13 и более переводов.

Comment: @rotabor изменил описание

Comment: @rotabor здравствуйте! Помогите еще с одной задачей пожалуйста

Comment: С какой? С этой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1548371/oracle-11g-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача: за определённый период для каждого отправителя 3-ёх и более переводов получателям 13-ти и более переводов от не менее 3-ёх уникальных отправителей переводов вывести сумму переводов.

Что-то на Oracle у меня не получилось схему построить, так что [сделал на MSSQLSever](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ecdbc/48), на Oracle сможете же переделать запрос?

```
WITH vts AS (SELECT * FROM view_transactions WHERE datedoc >= '01/01/2023' AND datedoc <= '01/29/2023')
SELECT t2.receiver, t2.sender, SUM(t2.amount) AS summary
FROM vts AS t2 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(receiver) AS core, receiver, COUNT(DISTINCT sender) as cds FROM vts
  GROUP BY receiver HAVING COUNT(receiver) >= 13 AND COUNT(DISTINCT sender) >= 3
) AS t1 ON t2.receiver = t1.receiver
GROUP BY t2.receiver, t2.sender HAVING COUNT(t2.sender) >= 3
```

Если нужно что-то ([valuta](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ecdbc/58)) добавить к результату:

```
WITH vts AS (SELECT * FROM view_transactions WHERE datedoc >= '01/01/2023' AND datedoc <= '01/29/2023')
SELECT t4.receiver, t4.sender, t4.summary, t5.valuta
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT receiver, sender, valuta FROM vts) AS t5 INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT t2.receiver, t2.sender, SUM(t2.amount) AS summary
  FROM vts AS t2 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(receiver) AS core, receiver, COUNT(DISTINCT sender) as cds FROM vts
    GROUP BY receiver HAVING COUNT(receiver) >= 13 AND COUNT(DISTINCT sender) >= 3
  ) AS t1 ON t2.receiver = t1.receiver
  GROUP BY t2.receiver, t2.sender HAVING COUNT(t2.sender) >= 3
) AS t4 ON t5.receiver = t4.receiver AND t5.sender = t4.sender
```

Хотя можно и так сделать, если всё в `view_transactions`:

```
WITH vts AS (SELECT * FROM view_transactions WHERE datedoc >= '01/01/2023' AND datedoc <= '01/29/2023')
SELECT t2.receiver, t2.sender, SUM(t2.amount) AS summary, MIN(t2.XXX) as XXX, ...
FROM vts AS t2 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(receiver) AS core, receiver, COUNT(DISTINCT sender) as cds FROM vts
  GROUP BY receiver HAVING COUNT(receiver) >= 13 AND COUNT(DISTINCT sender) >= 3
) AS t1 ON t2.receiver = t1.receiver
GROUP BY t2.receiver, t2.sender HAVING COUNT(t2.sender) >= 3
```

С дополнительным условием ([fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ecdbc/57)): за определённый период для каждого отправителя 3-ёх и более переводов получателям 13-ти и более переводов от не менее 3-ёх уникальных отправителей переводов вывести сумму переводов при условии, что сумма этих переводов больше 1000.

```
WITH vts AS (SELECT * FROM view_transactions WHERE datedoc >= '01/01/2023' AND datedoc <= '01/29/2023')
SELECT t3.receiver, t3.sender, t3.summary
FROM (
  SELECT t2.receiver, t2.sender, SUM(t2.amount) AS summary
  FROM vts AS t2 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(receiver) AS core, receiver, COUNT(DISTINCT sender) as cds FROM vts
    GROUP BY receiver HAVING COUNT(receiver) >= 13 AND COUNT(DISTINCT sender) >= 3
  ) AS t1 ON t2.receiver = t1.receiver
  GROUP BY t2.receiver, t2.sender HAVING COUNT(t2.sender) >= 3
) AS t3 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t7.receiver
  FROM vts as t7 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT t5.receiver, t5.sender, SUM(t5.amount) AS summary
      FROM vts AS t5 INNER JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(receiver) AS core, receiver, COUNT(DISTINCT sender) as cds FROM vts
        GROUP BY receiver HAVING COUNT(receiver) >= 13 AND COUNT(DISTINCT sender) >= 3
      ) AS t4 ON t5.receiver = t4.receiver
      GROUP BY t5.receiver, t5.sender HAVING COUNT(t5.sender) >= 3
  ) AS t6 ON t7.sender = t6.sender AND t7.receiver = t6.receiver
  GROUP BY t7.receiver HAVING SUM(t6.summary) >= 1000
) AS t8 ON t3.receiver = t8.receiver
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148729/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.