# ORACLE 11g - Вывести данные с определенной суммой а течение семи дней

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

На ORACLE 11g есть таблица transactions (транзакция), пример:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (id, sender_name, transaction_date, amount) AS
SELECT '1111', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-03 01:26:29', 700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2222', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-05 04:26:29', 450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3333', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-08 18:26:29', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4444', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-09 04:26:29', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT '6666', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2023-03-12 15:26:29', 845 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7777', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2023-03-19 11:00:29', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-26 01:26:29', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-08-29 02:26:29', 700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-10 03:26:29',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-11 08:26:29',  501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-17 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-09-30 05:26:29', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2023-10-01 05:26:29', 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Прошу прощения за такое, но мне нужна два варианта выборки данных:)))

1. Вариант
   Надо вывести транзакции клиента `(sender_name)` которого в общем сумме отправил денег более `(amount)` > 1000 в течение семи дней после первой отправки.
   В этом случае результат должен быть: все транзакции `Alice` потому что первый платеж  03.01 и в течение семи дней по 09.01 и у нее сумма транзакции в течение эти дней более 1000. И все транзакции `Betty` тоже логика такая. А у `Carol` результат должен быть транзакции 10.09, 11.09 и 17.09 тоже такая логика.
2. Вариант
   Можно ли определить начало недели (начиная с Понедельника) и вывести транзакции клиента осуществляемые в течение недели (с Понедельника по Воскресение) с общей суммой `amount` более 1000? Если да, то так можно делать.

Comment: `SUM(amount) OVER (... RANGE BETWEEN ..)` в CTE и отбор в основном запросе.

Comment: *Надо вывести **всех** транзакции клиента ...  у Carol результат должен быть транзакции 10.09, 11.09 и 17.09 тоже такая логика* - противоречие. Сначала говоришь что выводить все, а потом - только некоторые.

Comment: [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

Comment: А в чём проблема? Есть решение для предыдущего вопроса, есть подсказки для этого вопроса. Есть ещё куча всего на этом сайте (примеры CTE, аналитических, оконных функций) и на других. Есть всякие там SQL fiddles чтобы попробовать, или пользуйтесь оракловскими средствами разработки, там же наверняка что-то вроде Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio есть. Нужно пробовать самому. Лучше разбивать задачу на позадачи и решать их как более простые по сравнению со всей задачей, потом соединять.

Comment: Я потратил час или больше времени на ваш предыдущий вопрос (в себя вкладывал). Читайте документацию и пробуйте. Начнёте сами делать - поймёте, что в вашем вопросе описано плохо. Может, вы и сами задачу не до конца понимаете.

Comment: Вот подзадача № 1 - по дате определить день недели. Здесь нужно почитать документацию - наверняка есть такая стандартная функция. № 2. Выбрать записи, которые относятся к этой неделе. Это нужно сначала найти дату предшествующего понедельника и взять диапазон от него и до +6 дней. И так далее...

Comment: Вы нам тут покажите ваши попытки решения. Потом напишите, например: сделал это и это, нужно соединить, не могу, помогите. Мне, например, этой задачей уже заниматься не интересно. Я знаю, что могу её решить.

Comment: `по дате определить день недели` - можно через `trunc`